# What schedules logrotate?

Tags: cron, logrotate

I'm working on the program which creates a big log file.

I want to handle it with logrotate.

This is a configuration I put to `/etc/logrotate.d/`:

```
/var/log/myproject.log  {
 hourly
 maxsize 1
 rotate 6
 missingok
 notifempty
 compress
 nocreate
 copytruncate
 su www-data www-data 
}
```

(`/var/log/myproject.log` has owner `www-data`)

Commands

```
sudo logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.conf
```

and

```
sudo logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/myproject
```

rotate the log correctly.

However, after calling them `/etc/cron.hourly` is empty. Which means logrotate is not called hourly.

1. Am I guaranteed to have `logrotate` script in `/etc/cron.daily`?
2. Does the script check for frequency of update for log files. I.e. if I have `logrotate` script in `/etc/cron.daily` and for some log file `X` in `/etc/logrotate.d/` I set `weekly` setting, will `X` be rotated daily or weekly?
3. Can I just copy-paste `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` to `/etc/cron.hourly/`? Can I cut-and-paste?
4. Should I add `0anacron` file to `/etc/cron.hourly/`?
5. Should I do something else to enable hourly logging?

Comment: Tip for question 1: look at the output of `grep -r logrotate /etc/cron*`

Comment: @guntbert I've said it before and I'll say it again. You're a saint and a hero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. No.
2. From [`man logrotate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/logrotate):

   ```
   Each  configuration  file  can  set  global  options (local definitions
   override global ones, and later definitions override earlier ones)
   ```

   So, yes.
3. Again, from the manpage:

   ```
   hourly Log files are rotated every hour. Note that usually logrotate is
          configured  to  be  run  by  cron daily. You have to change this
          configuration and run logrotate hourly  to  be  able  to  really
          rotate logs hourly.
   ```

   So, yes, you should move the script. Inspecting the `cron.daily` script in my system, I think moving it should work fine.